# How did "Superhoodie" throw a paper airplane so accurately to Kelly across a lake?

Tags: misfits

In the Season 2 opener, "Superhoodie",

> later shown to be Simon,

throws a paper airplane across the lake with apparently pinpoint precision.  At this point, we know he has the following powers:

> The ability to travel back in time (one-way trip only), and immunity to all other powers. He may have precognition still, although it is possible that he gave up that power in exchange for the time-traveling power, as stealing it outright might be seen to be out of character for Simon.

We did see him practicing his parkour skills, but I don't remember him training his paper airplane-throwing skills, and I'm not sure any amount of practice would enable that throw.

He seemed pretty confident that it would land where he wanted it to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Superhoodie has the power to see the future. The present Simon has moderate control over his power, but we can assume that Superhoodie has already mastered it, so that is why he is able to control it and use it effectively. He is able to see every possible outcome, and we can assume that there is a one in a million chance that that a paper airplane could precisely hit Kelly in the eye. So with that one in a million chance, he is able to pinpoint its landing point.

At least, that's my explanation... I dunno, we might never really know.

Answer (score 5):

So far he has no powers that could let him throw an airplane so accurately, nor has he been shown training his throwing skills.

Answer (score 5):

Simon always had pretty good aim, though, didn't he?  He threw that dry roasted nut into the tattooist's mouth pretty right on, that time.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I don't think you could exactly have a power to throw a paper plane... I think he just threw it in her eye to get her attention, or it was by accident.

Comment: I don't know that your answer really adds much to the question.